# Why did Syd's body switch places with her mother's in the shower?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, legion

In the show, whenever Sydney switches places with someone, their minds swap bodies for a time.  When they return, the bodies stay where they are and the minds swap back (as expected).

In s2e4, in the shower scene, Sydney switches into her mother's body.  Then she (Sydney's mind, mother's body) goes to the shower and has sex with the man.  But when they switch back, suddenly (Sydney's mind, Sydney's body) is in the shower.  Why?

Just before the switch *back*, it pans across the room.  There's Sydney's body (as expected) with her mother's mind asleep in it.  Then the minds switch back and ... suddenly her mother's body is on the couch?

The mom is naked on the couch.  But the man is clearly surprised (he exclaims in some kind of shock/horror).  Sydney is fully dressed in the shower.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Syd switches back, the bodies actually switch places.

This can be seen in S01E01 with David. Syd and David switch minds and David(as Syd) leaves Clockworks but Syd(as David) gets picked up by Melanie's people. Then, when David and Syd's minds switch back, David (in his own body) is free but Syd (in her own body) is with the Summerland bunch.

Same with Syd and her mother. Syd switches minds with her mom and Syd(as Mom) has sex with mom's boyfriend while Mom(as Syd) is asleep in the other room. Then they switch back and now Mom (in her own body) is in the other room and walks into the bathroom to see Syd (in her own body) having sex with the boyfriend.

It does get a little confusing because the show tends to use the actor for the character whose mind is in control, so we saw Dan Stevens walk out of Clockworks in S01E01 and Rachel Keller picked up by the Summerland folks.

Comment: Ok, this is what I needed to know.  I don't think the body's swap places consistently.  In the scene with Syd and the cat, for example, the bodies don't switch places (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Legion Fan Wiki](https://legion.fandom.com/wiki/Sydney_Barrett), the reason this happened this way is because Sydney didn't have control over her body-swapping ability!

> Sydney first had sex when she was 16. Her mom was dating a journalist
>   at the time, and Syd and the journalist had a flirtation. When her mom
>   had passed out on the couch, Syd heard the journalist taking a shower.
>   **Using her ability, Sydney switched bodies with her mom and entered the
>   bathroom where the journalist was and they had sex. Unfortunately, Syd
>   did not have control over the body swap** and she changed back when he
>   was inside of her. Her mom then arrived and Syd recalled there being
>   lots of screaming that followed. Her mom thought that the journalist
>   was taking sexual advantage of Syd and called the police.

This could be furthered by the fact that they were able to get her into a hospital gown and restraints too without swapping minds too, suggesting her powers weren't working properly.

Comment: I'm still looking to see if I can find better confirmation from either Noah Hawley or the cast. If I find anything, I will surely edit and add it.